# Copy with rysnc without dotfiles in subfolder

Tags: backup, sync, rsync

I'm trying to backup Plex where I have lot's of music but Plex create file with dot and underscore. Like `Music/Rock/The Artist/._trackname.mp3`

`rsync -nvr --ignore-existing --exclude-from='rsync_exclude.txt' --stats source destination`

I put this in my `rsync_exclude.txt`. I tried lot's of stuff.

```
.*
\..*.mp3
\..*.jpeg
\..*.jpg
._.DS_Store
.DS_Store
.[a-z]*
```

Regex don't work. I have to be specific.

Without any success. Dry run still show me file like :
`Friends/._Acid Cave.mp3`

Comment: try with ```._*.mp3``` and let us know.

Comment: that's better 700 results rather than 8000 ! Thanks